# System IDs in android

Tags: android, xml

I've been following the Notepad tutorial, and I've noticed that I have to use `R.id.empty` and `R.id.list` in my XML file in order for the program to work.

What do these IDs mean?

Do I have to give all my lists the `R.id.list` ID?

I tried looking for them in the [reference page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id.html), but they have no description.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with R.id.empty, but using android.R.id.list is necessary when you're using a ListActivity with a custom layout.

See [android.app.ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html):

> ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)

Comment: Sometimes the framework uses known id values as a simple way for your app to tell it where to find specific components within a custom layout. ListActivity is one example of where this is used.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [ListActivity.java](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob_plain;f=core/java/android/app/ListActivity.java;h=4bf55184af669acd0702741cad70a50eaf863bc7;hb=HEAD)

```
@Override
public void onContentChanged() {
    super.onContentChanged();
    View emptyView = findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.empty);
    mList = (ListView)findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.list);
    if (mList == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is " +
                "'android.R.id.list'");
    }
    if (emptyView != null) {
        mList.setEmptyView(emptyView);
    }
    mList.setOnItemClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    if (mFinishedStart) {
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    mHandler.post(mRequestFocus);
    mFinishedStart = true;
}
```

That is why you should define "`android:id="@android:id/list"` in your xml to let ListActivity.java find the needed layout when executing `mList = (ListView)findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.list);`.

Comment: And what about `R.id.empty` ?

Comment: It is as the same as R.id.list.  If you define android:id="@android:id/empty in your xml. emptyView will not be null.